# Has any one had any luck using twitter bootstrap in the rails asset pipeline WITHOUT using a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, sprockets, twitter-bootstrap-rails

It seems ridiculous to me to have to use a gem to incorporate some stylesheets. I need a little more control over which of twitter bootstraps modules I'd like to use. It doesn't seem that any of the gems allow a buffet style option of importing what I need.

The problem with just throwing all of the less into a twitter folder in stylesheets/assets is that sprockets will import them all the time, and they fail when precompiling assets for production because the twitter mixins aren't imported into each file. This has been maddening, and every google search I try ends up leading to one of the boostrap-rails gems.

My current approach is to compile one less file for most of twitter bootstrap and import that, but I'm still getting some errors. Help?

Comment: You could fork one of those gems and modify it to your needs.

Comment: I could, but again, it seems like a lot of work for some stylesheets...

Comment: Why do you want to exclude modules? Download size?

Comment: I have a great solution for you! (but it includes using the bootstrap-sass gem)

Comment: Sergio - there are a few components that I'm just not interested in using (buttons, icon sprites, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I just merged the [assets folder of the bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/vendor/assets) with my assets folder and customized it according to my needs.

I am intentionally using the sass version of bootstrap, because less tends to cause conflicts  and seems to be badly supported by rails.